# Get all uppercase words using regex

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

So I want to get all uppercase words from a string using regex, but I want to get words grouped, and they will have one space between.I will give an example to clarify what I want. The words I want to get will have all letters uppercase.

"This is a UPPERCASE STRING, AND THIS IS ANOTHER one."

I would like to know if i can get the words like that:

First item: UPPERCASE STRING

Second item: AND THIS IS ANOTHER

Comment: Grouped by what exactly?

Comment: I gave an example of the output I want because I didn't knew how to explain better @Magnus, but I see that other understood my problem and gave me what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[A-Z\d]{2,}[ ][A-Z\d]{2,}\b` - min 2 letter two words separated by space
`[A-Z\d]{1,}[ ][A-Z\d]{1,}\b` - min 1 capital two letter words separated by space

Comment: I think I found a solution, "\b([A-Z]){3,}[^/s]([A-Z]){3,}([^/s])?(([A-Z]){3,})?\b". This is my regex, that get me what I want

Comment: but now I want to make the first 2 words mandatory

Comment: yes I think, if I have "I have WORD WORD", I want to take "WORD WORD", but if I have "I have just WORD", in this case i don't want to get "WORD". I hope my explication are ok.

Comment: @Rubyen "[A-Z\d]{2,}[ ][A-Z\d]{2,}\b" this is in accordance to your WORD WORD scenario

Answer (score 1):

I'm no regex expert but maybe this will work?

```
\b(?! )[ A-Z]+(?<! )\b
```

https://regexr.com/3ordm[1](https://regexr.com/3ordm)

Comment: You could replace `{1,}` with a `+`.

Comment: Great, updated my answer